# Print multiple lines as single line if they fit a pattern

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file with multiple lines and I want to join lines only if they fit a specific pattern. I know that I can join the lines with, for example:

```
$ cat input.txt
1
00:02:34,654 --> 00:02:36,554
Sean, let's go.

2
00:02:38,358 --> 00:02:40,724
Yeah. Detective. we got
a possible 1 87 out on Route 59.

3
00:03:04,584 --> 00:03:06,051
Right this way.

4
00:05:01,301 --> 00:05:03,269
How long has this been here?./
Tuesday.
```

```
$ cat input.txt | perl -00 -lpe '$i = 0; s/\n/(++$i > 2) ? " " : "\n"/ge'
1
00:02:34,654 --> 00:02:36,554
Sean, let's go.

2
00:02:38,358 --> 00:02:40,724
Yeah. Detective. we got a possible 1 87 out on Route 59.

3
00:03:04,584 --> 00:03:06,051
Right this way.

4
00:05:01,301 --> 00:05:03,269
How long has this been here?./ Tuesday.
```

But, how can I solve if the line fits the pattern (only if they have a `'/'`) ?. So in this case, the output I would like to achieve would be:

```
1
00:02:34,654 --> 00:02:36,554
Sean, let's go.

2
00:02:38,358 --> 00:02:40,724
Yeah. Detective. we got
a possible 1 87 out on Route 59.

3
00:03:04,584 --> 00:03:06,051
Right this way.

4
00:05:01,301 --> 00:05:03,269
How long has this been here?./ Tuesday.
```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday? What happened, and why are you asking again? What have you done in the meantime with the feedback you received the first time? Why is this tagged [tag:awk] if your solution is in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed '/\//{N;s/\n/ /;}'
```

- `/\//` if the line contains `/`
- `N` add newline and next line
- `s/\n/ /` replcae newline wiht a spce.